# How to create have a button call an async method?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 and have created a button.

```
button.clicked.connect(self.capture_image_async)
```

This button calls a method.

This method needs to be either async or call an async method within to get the results from the api.   The issue is that i cant get the button click to call the api.

I have tried asyncio and it just says that to read the response from the method it needs to be async.  Which again capture_image_async cant be async and have the button call it.

```
async def capture_image_async(self):
    # Implement your desired capture functionality here
    # e.g., save the current QImage to a file

    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            encoded_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()

            # Read the text from the textedit
            text = self.textedit.toPlainText()
            print("Start")

            # TODO make this async at some point
            response = await ask_API(text, encoded_frame)

            self.textedit.append(response)

            print("Complete")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Is there any way to have a button call an async method or have a synchronous method call an async method and get the response back.   The issue is my window is freezing and i want to avoid that.

1. async method called but button gives

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MainWindow.capture_image_async' was never awaited
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```